# How can Spotify stream without an html audio/video tag?

Tags: html, audio, spotify

When I search the HTML of the Spotify Web Player page with document.getElementsByTagName("audio"), there is no result.
Also, there is the little speaker icon in Google Chrome, which indicates that sound is coming from that tab. 
So how does Spotify create the sound, if not with the audio or video HTML element?

Comment: So apparently it was impossible for a web browsers to makes sounds before HTML5?